# Breadboard type for valve circuits?

Tags: high-voltage, breadboard

I want to play with valves running at 300V.

Is there some suitable form of breadboard or prototyping system that anyone is aware of?  Clearly you wouldn't use one of those common white push in things that you use to play with an Arduino.  Is there some home brew system that can be used?  I remember a long time ago there being electronics kits that had a bunch of springs that you clipped resistors into.  Is my only alternative to solder every circuit up every time?

Comment: "Play" + 300V = electrocution.

Comment: @winny   {"Play" + 300V = electrocution} = non constructive comment

Comment: **play**, _verb_, "to exercise or employ oneself in diversion, amusement, or recreation." Nothing wrong with that provided one assesses the risks and takes precautions to play safely.

Comment: Wasn't this what *bread boards* were originally "borrowed" from the kitchen for?

Comment: @transistor "play with an Arduino" doesn't sound like the type of clientele who puts safety first, but I hope I'm wrong.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

*Figure 1. Solder tag strips were standard for valve amplifier construction.*

[image]

*Figure 2. Screw terminal strips may provide a workable alternative for development work. Two of these blocks would be required spaced far enough apart that the large components could fit between them. The double-rows means that components can be replaced on the inner terminals without disturbing the wiring on the outer terminals.*

[image]

*Figure 3. For the man in a hurry, the rail mounted cage-clamp terminals might be the answer.*

[image] [image]

*Figure 4 and 5. The cage-clamp terminals hold wires in place using a spring cage. During insertion or removal he clamp is opened by levering with a small screwdriver through a slot adjacent to the spring.*

Answer (score 2):

Yes, of course! It's where the term  "breadboard" originated — from the concept of taking a largish board that you would slice bread on, mounting terminal strips and tube sockets on it using screws and standoffs, and wiring up your circuit. You are keeping a long-standing tradition alive!

Only after the circuit is working to your satisfaction do you take the time to bend and punch an aluminum chassis to hold it in a more permanent fashion.

Comment: +1. Iron nails make convenient single mounting points, rather than using tag strips as in the other answer. I've seen brass screws with cup washers used for the purpose - trap wires under the cup washer if you want to avoid soldering. If you go back to the 1920s you'll find capacitors (and occasionally resistors) with screw-down feet, and screw terminals, for exactly this purpose. For bonus points, make it legit : get an actual breadboard from a charity shop...

Answer (score 2):

I've been breadboarding tube circuits for over 60 years. I used to use wooden boards with screw-on terminals, but recently I've been using the plastic solderless boards which are designed for low-voltage semiconductor circuits.

> Clearly you wouldn't use one of those common white push in things...
> Despite appearances, these solderless breadboards can withstand quite high voltages. I tested some boards at voltages up to 600V, and had zero problems with shorting, arc-over, or even leakage current. I now consider them safe and effective for tube circuits. I even made a set of adaptors with DIP pins on the bottom and tube sockets on top.
> You still need to be careful, of course - tube circuit voltages can be deadly. Using fuses and/or current-limiting resistors on your power supply outputs is recommended. YMMV